# Equivalent in Spark of data type 'real'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for an equivalent in Spark of the type 'real' we can use in SQL. I saw that 'double' is the closest type of 'real'.

I tried to create a table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE customers (
  name string,
  salary real
)
partitioned by (country string, age integer)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3a://path-s3/customers/';
```

I got this error: 
`DataType real is not supported.`

1. Why can't we use this type in Spark?
2. What are the differences between 'real' and 'double'?

Thank you

Comment: _"the type 'real' we can use in SQL"_ > be careful, `REAL` is supposedly part of the standard, but the keyword is not supported by all dialects -- and when supported, its range/precision (and semantics e.g. `NaN` special value/values) differ widely from one database to another

Comment: Be careful also that _approximate_ data types have funny side effects e.g. `3.0/3.0*3.0` rarely equals `3.0`

Comment: `Real` is another name for `float`.  Which is another name for `approximate`, `inaccurate`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will use float then.